# hyperlink doesn't open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

i redesign my website and i have a problem with a hyperlink see my code i think the problem is in the js

```
<li class="product aopc">
        <a class="product-link"></a>
        <div class="product-details mCustomScrollbar">
    <a target="_blank" href="my link in pdf"><i class="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i></a>
    </li>
```

and a part of my js

```
// handle click events
$container.on( 'click', '.product', function( event ) {
    var $this = $( this );

    event.preventDefault();

    // if not already open, do so
    if ( !$this.hasClass( 'open' ) ){
        var $openItem = $container.find( '.open' );

        // if any, close currently open items
        if ( $openItem.length ) {
            closeItem( $openItem );
        }

        openItem( $this );
    }
});
```

and this:
      $container.on( 'click', '.close', function( event ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        closeItem( $( this ).closest( '.product' ) );
    });

```
function openItem( $item ) {
    var $image = $item.find( '.product-image' );

    $item.addClass( 'loading' ).spin( spinJsConfiguration );

    $image.attr( 'src', $image.data( 'src-large' ) );

    $item.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $item.spin( false ).removeClass( 'loading' ).addClass( 'open' );
        $container.addClass( 'item-open' ).isotope( 'reLayout' );
        $item.append( '<div class="close">&times;</div>' );
    });
}
function closeItem( $item ) {
    $item.removeClass( 'open' ).find( '.close' ).remove();
    $container.removeClass( 'item-open' ).isotope( 'reLayout' );
}
});
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you getting error?

Comment: What browser are you using? Safari won't open in new tab as of their security policy

Comment: the problem is not in the html because i have tested without the script and it's works, but i use isotope to filter products and with the script hyperlink doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link doesn't work because of the click handler. Your link is a child of the li **.product** .

The click handler contains preventDefault(). Removing that would make the link working again.

**Edit:**
Based on your comment, change the following:

```
$container.on( 'click', '.product', function( event ) {
    var $this = $( this );
```

To:

```
$container.on( 'click', '.product-link', function( event ) {
    var $this = $( this ).parent();
```

And **don't** remove  `preventDefault()`.

Comment: but if i remove this my script stop. i made a test on codepen http://codepen.io/nathel/pen/MyExeR

Comment: Updated the answer for you.

Comment: thanks Boratzan but when i click on the product the page reload

Comment: That's probably because you removed preventDefault. If you change the code like in my answer, you can leave the preventDefault where it was. Updated the answer again.

Comment: thanks Boratzan your saved my life, i am not comfortable with the javascript.